# How to get data from local json file using actions and axios.get() (Redux)?

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I wrote Action, should get data from db.json file. But

> **Error**: message "xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:8083/data/db.json 404
>   (Not Found)".

Why is it, if my path is correct (db.json is in the same folder)? In profileActions.js:

```
import axios from "axios";
var customData = require('./db.json');

export function fetchUsers(){
    return function(dispatch){
        axios.get('./db.json')
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({type:'FETCH_USERS_FULFILLED', payload:response.data});
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch({type:'FETCH_USERS_REJECTED', payload:err});
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving absolute path to db.json?

Comment: Please check https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/123

Comment: are u using webpack ?

Comment: The accepted answer is good. If you need more information then this is a good guide https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/fetch-data-from-a-json-file-in-a-react-app

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I meet the similar problem before.I create my react app by create-react-app command.And find that you can only get the static file from the public folder.If you want to the get "db.json",you should put the "db.json" into the public folder.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question is answered long back. It will help people like me. Instead of using axios or other network libraries you can directly import the json file like below and return it in dispatcher. If you are using local json to test it why do you need network libraries.

```
import data from './response.json'

export function initializeApp() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: ActionTypes.ActionName,
      payload: data
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the comment by theshubagrwl is a good read that helped , don't know how to upvote a comment ,

```
const getData=()=>{
fetch('data.json'
,{
  headers : { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
   }
}
)
  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
    setData(myJson)
  }); }
```

refer this code